# Error tying to run the command "npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save"

Tags: angular

Am new to Angular so am trying to follow tutorial on https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- angular-in-memory-web-api@0.8.0
  updated 1 package and audited 42609 packages in 21.447s
  found 5 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8551). You can ignore this warning since `fsevents` is required on macOS so it's skipped on windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is an optional dependency so you can just ignore it.

If you really want this message to disappear - try to update npm

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```

it can help.